# Swift : Extra Argument in call with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: swift, selector, nstimer, watchkit

I create a simple WatchApp Metronome. I use NSTimer with .scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, and I have an error **Extra Argument 'selector' in call**

Thanks for your answers

```
func playBeat() {

        if(self.State == true) {
            self.State == false
            [labelPlayPause.setTitle("Pause")]
        } else {
            self.State == true
            [labelPlayPause.setTitle("Play")]
        }

        BPMValue = 10
        var BPMInt:Int = Int(BPMValue)
        let value = "\(BPMInt) BPM"
        labelBPM.setText(value)
        let aSelector: Selector = "playBeat"

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60/self.BPMValue, target:self, selector: aSelector, userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a poor error message from Swift!

What this really means is that you need to ensure the types of each function parameter match the types of the values passed.

In your case, `BPMValue` is a `Float`, and `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` is expecting and `NSTimeInterval` as its first parameter. Note that `NSTimeInterval` (`Double`) and `Float` are not equivalent. In Objective-C you get an implicit conversion, this doesn't happen in Swift.

Try

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(60/self.BPMValue), target:self, selector: aSelector, userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
```

---

As a side note, you can be a little more terse with your code in Swift:

```
func playBeat() {

    if State {          // If State is a Bool, you can lose the '== true'
        State = false   // Must use set not comparison operator. No need to refer to 'self'.
        labelPlayPause.setTitle("Pause")
    } else {
        State = true  // Must use set not comparison operator.
        labelPlayPause.setTitle("Play")
    }

    BPMValue = 10
    var BPMInt = Int(BPMValue)    // Int Type is inferred
    let value = "\(BPMInt) BPM"
    labelBPM.setText(value)
    let aSelector: Selector = "playBeat"

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(60/self.BPMValue), target:self, selector: aSelector, userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
    })

}
```

Comment: I don't unserstand. BPMValue isn't Int, but a float. I convert BPMValue to Int for display in Label (BPMInt). I use in NSTimer the BPMValue as a float, no ?

Comment: No, NSTimeInterval is a typeAlias for Double, which is not equivalent to Float, so you cannot pass a float to it.

Comment: So you have to add either a Double, or an NSTimeInterval, but not a Float.

Comment: Have added edit noting that the original code uses comparison operators in two cases where it should be using set operators.